# Regex in Notepad++ : How to extract last part of URLs?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some URLS now i only want the last part of it 
for eg,

```
> http://www.12345.org/tiki-browse_gallery.php?galleryId=29
> http://www.12345.ie/shop/catalog/create_account.php?guest=guest
> http://www.12345.com/common/forms/default.asp?intID=181
```

I only want

```
tiki-browse_gallery.php?galleryId=29

shop/catalog/create_account.php?guest=guest

common/forms/default.asp?intID=181
```

Comment: Try [`\.[a-z]{2,3}\/([\w.?=/-]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lX8gL1/1)

Comment: It's copying the domain also

Comment: Try to replace `^.*?//.*?/` [with nothing](https://regex101.com/r/cH5zK7/1) and always show what regex you already tried please. The platform is for finding coding problems not for writing your code :p

Answer (score 1):

This regex will find the parts you want in find dialog

```regex
http[s]?://.*?/\K(.*)
```

If you put `$1` to `Replace With` and press replace all you will just have the parts you want in document.

> **\K**   :left matches are omitted